# Much Lower speeds on Laptop Ethernet than on WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, ethernet, mac-address

I have a new Laptop, about 6 months old (MSI GL63 9SD) . Up until now, I have always used to the WiFi to connect to the Internet, but now my router has died, I am replacing it with a new one, and trying to use the Ethernet until it arrives. However, the Internet speeds are terrible. My Internet speed is 60 Mbps, and I'm struggling to hit 100-200 Kbps on Ethernet. The Laptop has a Killer E2400 Ethernet. On Wifi, I had no problems. Here are the list of things I tried

- Running Ping test on cmd. I get 4-5 responses with a 32 Byte packet, then get a timeout. Everytime its the same.
- I connected the Ethernet to my desktop, everything works perfectly fine there. No timed out on Ping test, and getting the full speed of 60 Mbps.
- The above point made me think that my ISP is somehow blocking the MAC of my laptop, so I changed the MAC of my Laptop to that of the desktop, and connected to the Ethernet, but same problem.
- Messed around with the Speed and Duplex settings, didnt work.
- Called my ISP guy to ask if I somehow needed to register my devices to my ISP, but he said no.
- Disabled the Killer service on msconfig
- Tried updating the driver from Windows device manager, but it reports that I already have the best driver installed.
- Tried booting into a Ubuntu live session, and tested Internet speed. Download speeds are terrible, but Upload speeds as it should be. Same in Windows 10.

So what exactly is the Problem?? Laptop and Desktop have the same Internet settings.

Comment: Use the cable from desktop and connect it to the laptop and check the network speed.

Comment: Sounds like it could be an issue with the able itself. Like @Robert says, just test the laptop out with the Ethernet cable from the deskill machine: If the speed is then faster (aka: what is expected) you know the cable you used for the laptop is the issue. If the speed is still slow then there is some issue with the laptop; maybe a driver but possibly the physical connector itself.

Comment: But I used the same cable with both the laptop and the desktop